# How to add custom method all services spring data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I customizei a repository for all my repositories children have the same methods. The code is below the repository implementation.

**This interface:**

```
 @NoRepositoryBean
 public interface BaseMyRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>{

     List<T> findCustomNativeQuery(String sqlQuery);
 }
```

**This implementation class:**

```
 public class BaseMyRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements BaseMyRepository<T, ID>{

     private final EntityManager entityManager;

     public BaseMyRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager){
         super(entityInformation, entityManager);
         this.entityManager = entityManager;
     }

     @Transactional
     @Override
     public List<T> findCustomNativeQuery(String sqlQuery) {
         List<T> lista = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery, this.getDomainClass()).getResultList();

         return lista;
     }


 }
```

**This my repository:**

```
 public interface MyRepository extends BaseMyRepository<SmaempreEntity, Integer>{

 }
```

Now I need to know if is possible do exemplify the code below:

```java
 @Service
 @Transactional
 public class MyBaseService<R extends BaseMyRepository, E> {

     @Autowired
     private R;

     public List<E> findAll() {
         return R.findAll();
     }

    public List<E> findCustomNativeQuery(String sqlQuery) {
         return R.findCustomNativeQuery(sqlQuery);
     }
 }


 public class MyService extends MyBaseService<MyRepository, MyEntity> {


 }
```

Comment: You have all the code, just try to compile and run it.

Comment: Also see this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories

Comment: I do not know how to run the `@Autowired`